# Laravel: Working with a 3rd party bundle

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

This is a basic best practice question.

I started my first project using the Laravel framework. I just recently added the [L4withSentry](https://github.com/rydurham/L4withSentry) bundle to my laravel project. I followed the setup steps and everything is up and running fine, but I noticed that all of the code that's running for the site is running from the `vendor` folder of my project even though I published all of the views and assets.

Should I leave all of the code in the `vendor` folder and customize it there? I'm under the understanding that if I update composer and any of the vendor files need to be updated I'll lose all of my code. Should I move the controllers into my `app` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

packages should stay in the vendor folder. the sentry package makes it actually easy to customize or set your own model outside of sentry, so you don't have to fiddle with vendor packages.

if you *really* have to change some behaviour in a vendor package, you'd create a new class extending that vendor package's class.